# Not able to run azure databricks from python file

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks

I want to run azure databricks notebook from a python file I have client_id, secret and token id. I tried to run it by creating a databricks client but there is no package that can run a databricks notebook it seems. TIA for any suggestions

The answer should run a data bricks notebook like we run a datafactory like this code does

```
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
run_response = adf_client.pipelines.create_run(rg_name, df_name, df_pipeline_name, parameters=...............

pipeline_run = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(rg_name, df_name, run_response.run_id)
status = pipeline_run.status
    
while status == 'Queued' or status == 'InProgress':
    time.sleep(5)
    status = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(rg_name, df_name, run_response.run_id).status
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the databricks rest APIs to trigger databricks jobs. You have to first configure a job with a cluster and a notebook.

You can check [this blog](https://medium.com/@anupamchand/trigger-a-spark-job-on-databricks-using-rest-api-940227616768) which demonstrates this. The blog talks about calling the APIs via postman. You just have to replace this with python code.

The official databricks rest API documentation to trigger a job can be found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunNow). [Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-api.html) also shows how to call the APIs using python code.

You can use a databricks token or AAD bearer token for authorization.

Comment: That was my question I cannot find any reliable python package to run the job

Comment: @Sam Have you see this already https://pypi.org/project/databricks-api/ ?

Comment: Yeah but it asks for token and I don't have that I can only use service principal maybe there is a way to extract token from service principal

Comment: This information is available on google. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token. This shows how to get the access token which is valid for 1 hour. The article shows how to fetch the token using curl but You can configure your same python code to  fetch a new access token by calling the AAD rest API.

Comment: I am able to access the token by using these commands

from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential, DefaultAzureCredential
credential = ClientSecretCredential(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, tenant_id = tenant_id)
token = credential.get_token(".default")

But I am unable to create a job using this its showing valid error 404